# MongoTemplate null pointer exception in class

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

I have been looking at other answers but none of the seem to work for me, I have a spring boot application where I am using mongo and kafka. In the main class where my `run()` method is I am able to `@Autowired` mongoTemplate and it works but then in another class I did the same and I am getting a null pointer exception on the mongoTemplate.

Here are both classes:

Working

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ProducerConsumerApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

public static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProducerConsumerApplication.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ProducerConsumerApplication.class, args).close();
}

@Autowired
private Sender sender;

@Autowired
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;


@Override
public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.setCurrentNode("my_node");
    msg.setStartTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String json = "{ \"color\" : \"Orange\", \"type\" : \"BMW\" }";
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    msg.setTest(objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>(){}));
    sender.send(msg);

    mongoTemplate.createCollection("test123");
    mongoTemplate.dropCollection("test123");



}
```

Not working

```
@Component
public class ParentNode extends Node{
@Autowired
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

public void execute(Message message) {

    try{

        // GET WORKFLOWS COLLECTION
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("workflows"); 


    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Thank you for the help. It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

can you try to inject dependency with setter or constructor:

Method 1:

```
@Component
public class ParentNode extends Node{

  @Autowired
  public ParentNode(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate){
    this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
  }

  private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

  public void execute(Message message) {

  try{

      // GET WORKFLOWS COLLECTION
      MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("workflows"); 


  } catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Method 2:

```
@Component
public class ParentNode extends Node{

  @Autowired
  public void setMongoTemplate(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate){
    ParentNode.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
  }

  static private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

  public void execute(Message message) {

  try{

      // GET WORKFLOWS COLLECTION
      MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("workflows"); 


  } catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```